# An out of bag testing procedure I developed. Is it biased?

Tags: prediction, bootstrap, out-of-sample

Trying to estimate the error of a prediction model trained on a combined group vs a subset of interest within that group (for example, Men)

My procedure is

1. First simulate a random subset like the subset of interest (so for example, choose 50% at random to be in this control group)
2. Train on a bootstrap sample of the combined group (so men and women combined)
3. Then from the out of bag leftover, subset on the FAKE random subset (generated in step 1) and sample  from that. Test the model on this and get AUC, Brier score, etc.
4. Then from the same out of bag leftover, subset on the original subset of interest (e.g. males) and sample from that (thus can overlap with #2). Test again on this sample and get statistics.

And iterate 2-4 about 1000 times to get distributions of model performance (e.g. AUC, Brier Score). The distributions of 2 and 3 should be similar under the null that males are essentially randomly chosen from the original population in terms of impact on AUC of the model.

The purpose is to identify differences in model performance on subsets and compare between different kinds of subsets (e.g. race, gender, SES etc.)

One problem I have is there is a lot of sampling error involved in creating the fake subset. Although you iterate 1000 times you only choose that fake subset once.

Comment: I don't understan your step 3. Also: What are you doing with the sets generated in step 2 and 3? Where exactly do you calculate your performance figures of merit? What do you use them for? What do you want to achieve? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I've updated the question to answer your questions. Please let me know if anything is still missing

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your question. Maybe someone else does and chimes in.